# Force Word 2013 to always paste images in-line with text

Tags: microsoft-word, images, paste

For years (ages?) I've been pasting images to Word and it always was pasting them with:

- *Layout Options > In Line with Text > In Line with Text*

Since I've been using this paste mode for about 20+ years, it has become my *de facto* standard.

Since switching to Word 2013, I can clearly see that each time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> Word 2013 is pasting any image with:

- *Layout Options > With Text Wrapping > Top and Botton*

And I have to manually switch to my *de facto* standard each time, which is pretty annoying.

Is there any way (configuration option) to tell Word, which layout option I want all my images to be pasted in? I know that I can change default pasting option for text (i.e. with / without formatting) and I have actually changed this as well. But, what about default pasting options for images in Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **File** tab in Word choose **Options > Advanced** and then scroll down to the **Cut, copy, and Paste** group of options. From there select **Insert/paste pictures as:** menu control and from it choose `In line with text`.

[image]

Comment: God! Shame on me, I was that close! :> Thank you...